# Generic error messages when compiling basic program through mac terminal

Tags: java, xcode, emacs

I am using linux and emacs, I got a program working fine on one computer but when I try to compile it through my mac terminal it refuses to work, giving an error message that reads as follows:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:uni_shit James$ javac /Users/James/Desktop/uni_shit/cp4a.java
/Users/James/Desktop/uni_shit/cp4a.java:43: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
1 error
```

The code is copied and pasted from what was working perfectly. Here is my code:

http://s30.postimg.org/9zmp2rr35/Screen_Shot_2014_10_08_at_18_20_43.png

Comment: Hint: Paste your code, select it, then click the {} icon at the top of the editor

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the code in your image is the exact code you're trying to execute? The problem is almost certainly a mismatched/extraneous curly brace, code lying outside of a class declaration or other formatting issue. Indent every line of code that falls within curly braces -- it'll make spotting these types of issues much easier, even when using an editor or IDE that lacks brace matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've pasted everything from the terminal running Emacs into the Xcode editor, *including* the status bar Emacs prints at the bottom (which is not part of your code). Delete everything from `-uuu` to the end of the file.

In the future, save the file in Emacs (e.g. on a flash drive or online storage) and open it up in Xcode (or whatever editor you choose), rather than copying and pasting. That will cut down on errors like this; and besides, you might have a program longer than one screen some day.

I should add, in case you're interested, that Emacs works fine on Macs too. There's actually a version of it included in OS X, although it's pretty old; for the current version, there are a few options to choose from, of which the most popular seem to be [Emacs For OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/). The main difference is that Aquamacs acts a little more like a Mac app in its handling of keyboard shortcuts and things like that; but the standard one also includes nice <kbd>Command</kbd> key shortcuts for a lot of things.